# How to calculate the series?

Tags: power-series, closed-form

How can we calculate the series:
$$
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-x^n}
$$
I found that
$$
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\Big(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(x^n)^m\Big)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{1}{1+x^m}\Big).
$$
Any suggestion?

EDIT: I once set if $\vert x\vert<1$, but the series doesn't converge at all. So In what occasion does the series converge?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $|x|\gt1$, the series converges since $|x^n-1|\geqslant\frac12|x|^n$ for every $n$ large enough, and $$F(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x^n-1}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n+1}x^{-n}\frac1{1-x^{-n}}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n+1}x^{-n}\sum_{k\geqslant0}x^{-nk},$$ that is, $$F(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\alpha_nx^{-n},\qquad\alpha_n=\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{d+1}.$$ 
Note that $$\alpha_n=\sum_{d\mid n}1-2\sum_{d\mid n,\ d\ \mathrm{even}}1=\sigma_0(n)-2\sigma_0^{(e)}(n)=\sigma_0(n)-2\sigma_0(n/2)\mathbf 1_{n\ \text{even}},$$
see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EvenDivisorFunction.html),
where $\sigma_0(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. The generating function of the sequence $(\sigma_0(n))$ is [known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html), hence all this yields, for every $|z|\lt1$, $z\ne0$, 
$$F(z^{-1})=\frac{\psi_z(1)+\log(1-z)}{\log z}-2\frac{\psi_{z^2}(1)+\log(1-z^2)}{\log(z^2)},$$ and, finally, $$F(z^{-1})=\frac{\psi_z(1)-\psi_{z^2}(1)-\log(1+z)}{\log z}.$$ As usual, this formula, based on the so-called [q-polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) (see also (5)-(6)-(7) [there](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html)), is, as given, a mere rewriting of the series one started with.

Comment: Thank you. But What I asked is not real you answered.

Comment: @Did Your comparison was nicer. Really cool how the divisor function comes up too. +1

Comment: What is $\psi_{1/x}$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Sorry, I somehow forgot to include the link I had in mind. Done now. Thanks.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Is there a typo in the MathWorld article, or am I bad at reading? It states the generating function and then says $\phi$ for $\psi$ (I think) ... they're talking about [this thing](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) anyway, so I'll try to read that (haven't taken any complex analysis yet so I will probably not succeed in understanding it).

Comment: @Did: In my question, $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{1-x^n}$, while you stated that $a_n=\frac{1}{x^n-1}$. I don't think this two facts are equivalent.

Comment: @Roger209 Right, somehow the $(-1)^n$ had escaped me. Sorry about this. See revised version.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Yes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer between the two horizontal lines was to the original question, which specified $|x| <1$.

---

This doesn't converge. If the sum is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n
$$

with

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{1-x^n}
$$

then, since $|x|<1$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0 \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} 1-x^n = 1$$

This gives

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n \,\,= \,\,\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1-x^n}\,\,\, =\,\,\, \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n$$

Clearly, this limit doesn't exist. The terms don't go to zero, so the sum cannot possibly converge.

---

In response to your edited question, the condition on $x$ for which the series converges is exactly $|x|>1$.

When $x>1$ we get an alternating series in which the terms $a_n$ go to zero, so it must converge.

If $x<-1$, we get a non-alternating series in which the terms go to zero as well. This converges by comparison:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(-x)^n-1} < 1 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{-x})^n}$$

The right hand side above converges because it's a geometric series with a common ratio that is greater than zero and less than one.

Comment: But what if $|x|>1$?

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidH $|x|<1$ is given in the question ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: I'am sorry, but I just made a change. What shall we do now?

Comment: @Roger209 I've edited in an answer to your second question.

Comment: Alternating? $ $

Comment: @Did how is it now?

Comment: Now you seem to use $t^n-1\geqslant t^{n/2}$ for every $t\gt1$. Is that so?

Comment: @Did That's what I was going for - I think that's true for all sufficiently large $n$

Comment: There are simpler ways (see the first line of my answer).