# How to calculate the series in the modified form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

How can we calculate the series:
$$
F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{1-x^n}
$$

Link: [how to calculate the series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074325/how-to-calculate-the-series/1074332?noredirect=1#comment2185201_1074332)

Comment: What is $x$ in this case?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: $x$ should be any real value that can ensure the convergence of the series.

Comment: Dividing the numerator and denominator at the right by $x^n$ you'll get the $-F(1/x)$ from your previous question.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Yar, thank you.